# ¿Se puede dar formato a MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en la que la llave primaria tiene formato `'BCB001'`, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de dar formato a `AUTO_INCREMENT` para que pueda llenar el campo que necesito.

Comment: El atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT` es para campos de tipo `INT`  , y no para los  de tipo `varchar` o `char`.

Comment: En referencia al comentario anterior, lo que podrías hacer es tener un campo `auto_increment` e internamente en tu aplicación mostrar 'BCB' + 1 cuando tuvieras que hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El campo auto incremental fue creado precisamente para no ser tocado por el usuario, haciendo posible generar cambios y borrar datos de la DB sin generar daños colaterales. Además de facilitar la integridad referencial de los mismos.

Si todo esto todavía no te convenció el `AUTO-INCREMENT` es para int, no para atributos de varchar, por lo que no podrías hacer lo que estás queriendo.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería crear un campo `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` en tu tabla aparte del código para guardar el formato deseado.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Luego crear un Trigger para actualizar el campo `cod` **before** *(antes)* , haciendo uso de la función [Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para concatenar el formato fijo `(BCB)` con lo que devuelve [LPad](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) *(numero,cantidad,chararrellenar)* rellenando con `0` a la izquierda a lo que devuelte la función [LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) **+1** *(ultimoidinsertado)* , no sobrepasando el `Length` en este ejemplo es 3           *(segundoparametro)*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prueba)=0   THEN
        SET NEW.cod= 'BCB001';
    else
        SET NEW.cod= CONCAT('BCB', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID()+1, 3, '0'));
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Para insertar solo haría el `INSERT` clásico.

```
INSERT INTO test (nombre) values ('Nombre1');
```